# tinymce creating quick responses / keyboard shortcuts

Tags: tinymce

I was wondering whether there is a way we can create "shortcuts" in tinymce so when typing a specific phrase, it'll change it to a full sentence from an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textpattern` plugin can solve this for you:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/textpattern/

For example this could be in your configuration:

```
textpattern_patterns: [
  {start: '--', replacement: '&mdash;'},
  {start: '//brb', replacement: 'Be Right Back'},
],
```

Comment: exactly what i want! although, can this be created from an array? I'd like to retrieve the array using an Ajax call

Comment: The TinyMCE configuration expects the exact structure you see above.  When you call `tinymce.init({})` the structure needs to exist as shown above - how you get that data is up to you.  Can you use AJAX - sure.

Comment: thanks @Miahcel Fromin, just posted another question on the Ajax call. I tried a few things but couldn't manage to get it working 100% - not sure if you have any ideas?